# Django m2m check in pre/post_save signal

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to be able to check if at least one of *n* many-to-many fields has been set before saving.

I am using **DRF** alongside **Django 3.0**. I have a lot of models with many ManyToMany fields and I want to be able to check if at least one of certain fields is set. Also being tied to a certain serializer is not really an option since I want this rule to be checked even while updating etc.

At first I wanted to do this with signals - *post_save* and *m2m_changed*. But whenever a model is saved with no m2m field set, the signal doesn't fire and I am unable to know if that field had been set in the request.

The only option which I can think of is to set up some other thread that will fire up when *post_save* signal is received and will wait for *m2m_changed* signal. However I am not sure if these signals are fired up asynchronously or one by one.

Could you please help me?

Comment: You want to do some sort of validation. validations should be in your serializer. the other option is just bad and you should avoid it.

Comment: Okay I'll stick with the serializer option. Though it will be pretty annoying to create serializers for modification and having to add all the checks again, since it is a very large database.